# Xubuntu 20.04 Failed to finalize DM devices on shutdown

Tags: 20.04, shutdown

On shutdown I get several error messages.

```
ln: /tmp/mountroot-fail-hooks.d//scripts/init-premount/lvm2: No such file or directory
/dev/mapper/myvg-main: clean 428987/22929408 files, 6648808/91686912 blocks
[    36.380403] systemd-shutdown[1]: Failed to finalize DM devices, ignoring
```

The system is shutting down after those messages and I can boot without problems. I'm using Xubuntu 20.04.
How can I solve this?